# View Zoom image without scrolling

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, position

I have implemented a visual web-part for displaying some item. each of the item consisting of it's picture and it's description. I have implemented the some code for displaying this. and I got the result. this is my code.

```
 function hoverdiv(e, control) {

    var left = e.clientX + "px";
    var top = e.clientY + "px";

    var newImg = $(control).attr("src");
    $("#imgView").attr("src", newImg);

    $("#dialog").css('left', left);
    $("#dialog").css('top', top);
    $("#dialog").css('position', 'fixed');
    $("#dialog").toggle(); return false;
}
```

But some times the user hovered the mouse pointer in one image which will zoom near to the mouse pointer. If the user wish too the whole image. he has to scroll down for achieving this.

[image: It's showing like this]

How Can show the zoom image without any scrolling. Can any body suggest please? It would be very grateful for me to complete my task. thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can check these links:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sapnabeniwal/move-mouse-on-image-for-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-effect/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sapnabeniwal/a-mousehover-zoom-effect-using-jquery-and-css/

I am sure this will definitely help you.